# Reference syntax does not match behavior for replace()

Tags: javascript

The function below does not work unless I assume that .replace returns the new string.  The syntax implies that the input string itself it modified.

**MDN**

```
str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubStr|function[, Non-standardflags]);
```

**Code**

```
escape: function ( second_split )
{
    for( element in second_split )
    {
    second_split[element] = second_split[element].replace('**', '*');
    second_split[element] = second_split[element].replace('*|', '|');
    }
return second_split;
},
```

Comment: No. Primitive strings are immutable. `replace` returns the new value.

Comment: "*However in documentation at MDN there is no mention of a return value.*". First sentence on MDN: "*Returns a new string ...*".

Comment: @Sime...sorry edited to Reference - syntax does not match behavior which it does not.

Comment: Yea, I get you. Should be `newstring = str.replace(...);` for clarity.

Comment: I have updated the documentation. Many of the other methods seem to miss the `newstring =` part, probably because of the *Summary* section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MDN:

> This method does not change the String object it is called on. It simply returns a new string.

Also, from the summary at the top:

> Returns a new string with...

So replace returns a new string. Strings are immutable, so doing anything else would not make sense.

Comment: I just looked at the fucntion prototype ..in ohter prototypes they have the return value listed...getElementById for example.  A bit inconsistent.

Comment: Yeah, they should probably include the return value there. Aren't the docs editable like a wiki? I'm not sure exactly how it works, but maybe you could fix it or ask somebody to fix it for you?